# Facebook Links being blocked from preview

Tags: links, facebook

Someone in Facebook posted a link to my site. Facebook tries to show a preview of the page with the link but it only shows "403 Forbidden". I am sure that I am somewhere blocking this Facebook request but am not sure what the issue is. For example, I only accept `GET` `POST` and `HEAD` requests and perhaps this is some other kind of request.

The link looks like this (with the site name changed).

```
<a class="_52c6" href="https://www.example.com/index.php?topid=1&amp;grade=4&amp;page=Movement" tabindex="-1" target="_blank" data-lynx-mode="async" rel="nofollow" data-lynx-uri="https://l.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Findex.php%3Ftopid%3D1%26grade%3D4%26page%3DMovement&amp;h=ATMXgEds4Ymh3lFXLPXBbWVCIpDtJE_0gYVzgWTVdbsPfrBr6vIr7CJhYxkxDpQpB-js2Yl91RpOiRU5q8XFbZyvtVspSVZ6WG7tIB6rQkV2-nP8iIskWlN5Tha441w7nfGx9aaby2TmQdT9QMNt0IpGsXttslzB6GXaX7fnbgWJyHfCyJN-BdTKtO9V-gXtJc6IFiRqcSsa57JSXgNDTRq50D-dkMIl4YLFaUYN4xL8ozIOZMakcDxjgksMUx9G"></a>
```

Each time I load the Facebook page, I would expect to get a request in my server log that I am blocking, but I don't see any. Can you help me pinpoint what is going on here?

Comment: Facebook doesn't refresh the preview on every page load.  Try sharing a new link to your site and look for requests from the user agent `facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)`

Comment: That was it. I have a long list of "bad bots" that I block access to in order to reduce traffic and this user agent was added to it. My list is kept and processed in `php` but if a certain threshold of hits is reached from a "bad bot" user agent, then that user agent is automatically added to a `RewriteCond ` in `.htaccess.` Because it was added to `.htaccess`, my error log of blocked requests (generated in php) didn't contain a trace of it. It is good to know my `.htaccess` blocking is working.

Answer (score 1):

The [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) is the tool you want - you need to be logged in to Facebook to use it.

This will allow you to test a URL, and see both what Facebook has cached, and request an updated scrape:

[image: Example response for a URL]

You can also submit a list of URLs that you'd like to be invalidated from the Cache so that you can refresh a bunch of pages if required.